# How to show Custom Post Types under Taxonomy in a new WordPress page template?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, custom-taxonomy

I have created this plugin with Quiz as CPT and subjects as Taxonomy. I need to show the CPTs under the Taxonomy in a list type. But, for now reason it's not showing here are the code -

Register quiz CPT and subjects as taxonomy

```
/**
 * Register a custom post type called "quiz".
 *
 * @see get_post_type_labels() for label keys.
 */
function wpqb_init() {
    $label = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'WP Quiz Bank', 'qb' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Quiz Bank', 'qb' ),
        'menu_name'             => _x( 'WP Quiz Bank', 'qb' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => _x( 'WP Quiz', 'qb' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add Quiz', 'qb' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Quiz', 'qb' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Test', 'qb' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Quiz', 'qb' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Quiz', 'qb' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Quizes', 'qb' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Quiz', 'qb' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Quiz:', 'qb' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'No Quiz found.', 'qb' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'No quiz found in Trash.', 'qb' ),
        'featured_image'        => _x( 'Quiz Cover Image', 'qb' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => _x( 'Set Quiz cover image', 'qb' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => _x( 'Remove Quiz cover image', 'qb' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => _x( 'Use as Quiz cover image', 'qb' ),
        'archives'              => _x( 'Quiz archives', 'qb' ),
        'show_ui' => true,
    );     

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $label,
        'description'        => 'Quiz custom post type',
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail'),
        'show_in_rest'       => false,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'Quiz' ),
        'menu_position'      => 20,
        'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-welcome-learn-more',
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,

        //'taxonomies'         => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
       
    );
      
    register_post_type( 'Quiz', $args );


    // Add new taxonomy, NOT hierarchical (like tags)
    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'Subjects', 'qb' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Subject', 'qb' ),
        'search_items'               => __( 'Search Subjects', 'qb' ),
        'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Subjects', 'qb' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'All Subjects', 'qb' ),
        'parent_item'                => null,
        'parent_item_colon'          => null,
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Subject', 'qb' ),
        'update_item'                => __( 'Update Subject', 'qb' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Subject', 'qb' ),
        'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Subject Name', 'qb' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate Subjects with commas', 'qb' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove Subjects', 'qb' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used Subjects', 'qb' ),
        'not_found'                  => __( 'No Subjects found.', 'qb' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Subjects', 'qb' ),
    );
 
    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'labels'                => $labels,

        'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'subjects' ),
    );
 
    register_taxonomy( 'subjects', 'quiz', $args );


}
add_action( 'init', 'wpqb_init' );
```

And the page template code

```
<!-- show cpt with taxonomy -->
    <?php
        $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'subjects', 'posts_per_page' => '3' ) );

            if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :

                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

                    // get all of the terms for this post, with the taxonomy of categories-projets.
                    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'quiz' );
                    the_title();

                    // create the span element, and write out the date this post was created.
                    echo "<div>" ;

                    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                        echo $term->name;
                    }

                    echo "</div>";


                endwhile;
                wp_reset_query();

            endif;
    ?>
```

Any help would be appreicated

Comment: Your `get_the_terms()` arguments are incorrect - the second should be the name of your taxonomy, not the post type.

Comment: @bosco Tried, still don't show

Answer (score 0):

I see a few things that may be causing problems.

To answer your question though, this line:

`$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'subjects', 'posts_per_page' => '3' ) );`

is performing a query on a post type called "subjects".

I think you want to be pulling your quizzes.  So the line should be:

`$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'quiz', 'posts_per_page' => '3' ) );`

I'd go through and check capitalization as well.  When you registered your post type you called it "Quiz", but later referred to it as "quiz".  It should be lowercase.  You did this as well when you changed the CPT slug.

Comment: Change all capital Quiz case to lowercase, change the post type subjects to quiz still it doesn't show anything, any other suggestion?

Comment: did you change the line above?  I've tested on my system and it's working.  Check if your CPT are still present now that you removed capitalization's too.